# How can I solve this validity statement ?

Tags: logic

The study of a class of substances (a, b, c, d) has led to the 
following results:

● If a and b appear so does precisely one of c or d.

● If b and c appear, then both or neither of a, d appears.

● If neither of a, b appears then neither of c, d appears.

● If neither of c ,d appears then neither of a, b appears.

Show that not all three of a, b, c can occur (occur together) and

if a, b are both missing then so is c.

P.S = Should I write these sentences to the propositional formula ?

Comment: Well did you at least try that?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't reach the solution @Hakim

Answer (score 1):

(1) If $a$, $b$ and $c$ occur together, then, by the first rule, $d$ doesn't. Now you know the state of all four events. Are the other rules satisfied in that situation?

(2) This is a special case of the third rule.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over the problem -- since it is propositional, I just auto-generated the proofs in sequent calculus.

This is for problem (1):

[image: LK Proof of (1)]

And this for problem (2):
[image: LK Proof of (2)]

Just as a remark: there are certainly shorter and more intuitive proofs of both statements, but the convenient thing about a formal proof is that it "just works".